# How to use postgres cursor within Python code

Tags: python, postgresql, stored-procedures, cursor, psycopg2

I have a stored function in postgres:

```
CREATE FUNCTION return_curs() RETURNS refcursor AS $$
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor_x FOR SELECT col FROM table_y;
    RETURN cursor_x;
END; $$
```

Then in Python I want to invoke the procedure to fetch returnung cursor row by row for exapmle using psycopg2.
Are there any way to perform this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to let `psycopg2` do the [server side cursor](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors) creation work [just by naming it](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.cursor):

```
cursor = conn.cursor(name='cursor_x')
query = "select * from t"
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor:
    print row
```

To use a returning cursor function execute it as usual:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.callproc('return_curs')
```

Then catch the returned cursor with a named cursor:

```
named_cursor = conn.cursor(name='cursor_x')
for row in named_cursor:
    print row
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about server side cursors, but here we need to utilize somehow existing stored functions in the DB.